# Lighting for easily spotting mosquitoes?

Tags: pest-control, light

I can effectively zap mosquitoes with a hand racket zapper once I see them. A LED flashlight in a dark room seems to work best for spotting the mosquitoes while they fly. Can someone recommend better lighting options to see and expose them?

Comment: If you're having a particularly terrible time with them, couldn't you hang a bug zapper that attracts them for like an hour or so in each of the problem rooms?

Comment: @SolarLunix Mosquitoes mostly ignores bug zappers. They are attracted to CO2 and prefer dark surfaces. So bug zappers actually are only killing harmless and possibly beneficial insects, but using a racket zapper I can easily kill the mosquitoes in my room!

Comment: Have you tried using oils around your home? http://www.healthline.com/health/kinds-of-natural-mosquito-repellant

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a single light bulb in a lamp. Turn off all the other lights and then the bugs will be drawn to that one area. should be able to pick a good number off that way. Happy Hunting

Comment: Unfortunately the light bulb is not very attractive to the mosquitoes, and I dont mind other bugs.